How to not override multiple transition properties?
I have an element which can have different transitions on different events.
In the example below, the square becomes orange when you hover it, and become longer or larger if you toggle one of the checkboxes.
These transitions are not active when you remove the w-100 or h-100 class, or on mouseout.
The problem occurs when multiple events are active on the same time because the properties will be overridden so only the last active declared event will work
What's the best way to keep all these events active no matter the situation ?


#square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#square:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: background-color 400ms;
}

#toggleWidth:checked~#square {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 500ms;
}

#toggleHeight:checked~#square {
  height: 100px;
  transition: height 600ms;
}

#toggleBorderRadius:checked~#square {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleWidth" name="toggleWidth" />
<label for="toggleWidth">Toggle width</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggleHeight" name="toggleHeight" />
<label for="toggleHeight">Toggle height</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggleBorderRadius" name="toggleBorderRadius" />
<label for="toggleBorderRadius">Toggle border radius (no transition)</label>

<br><br>
<div id="square"></div>




I believe specifying the individual transition properties is the way to go here. I don't think there is another way to do this.

If you mean like I did in the snippet, you can see that if you hover the square when one of the checkbox is toggled, you won't get the background-color transition because it will be overriden

Do you want the properties to transition when they are removed (e.g. the width to take time to shrink back to its original value) or do you want the change to be sudden (which is what it looks like now as transition is set only when the class is set),

I want the change to be sudden to make it more specific and see how to handle it.

Since the durations are all the same, you could simply go with transition: all 500ms in each of the three cases here. Or, if other properties might changes as well, but you don't want to transition those too - explicitly mention all the properties you want to transition, in all three cases then.

You got a point, but because my goal is to declare it in a specific way, I edited my question in that way.

You can use CSS variables to set the transitions as you want. Here's an example:


#square {
  --transitionw: width 0s;
  --transitionh: height 0s;
  --transitionbg: background-color 0s;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: var(--transitionw), var(--transitionh), var(--transitionbg);
}

#square:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  --transitionbg: background-color 2000ms;
}

#toggleWidth:checked~#square {
  width: 100px;
  --transitionw: width 2000ms;
}

#toggleHeight:checked~#square {
  height: 100px;
  --transitionh: height 2000ms;
}
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleWidth" name="toggleWidth" />
<label for="toggleWidth">Toggle width</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleHeight" name="toggleHeight" />
<label for="toggleHeight">Toggle height</label>
<br><br>
<div id="square"></div>



